# Http endpoint for IOT hub resource

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sdk, azure-functions

How to get the http endpoint of an iot hub in azure. I need to build a solution to ping the http url to test whether iot hub is active or down. Similar to availability check.

Comment: Status of the iot hub , is that what you want ?

Comment: yes the status ...but.want to invoke this url outside azure portal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can create an Azure Function or whatever you favor, to invoke this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/getstats) to obtain the status. Example response will be like this

```
{
  "totalDeviceCount": 0,
  "enabledDeviceCount": 0,
  "disabledDeviceCount": 0
}
```

To Authenticate against `AZURE API` you need to obtain the `BEARER` token first.
Example :

```
private const string Resource = "https://management.azure.com/";
string authority = $"https://login.windows.net/"TenantId";
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var credential = new ClientCredential("ClientId", "ClientSecret");
var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Resource, credential).Result;
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

Now when you call any azure resource api, pass the bearer token along

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this and will get this error when i hit this api .{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}

Comment: @jubi you need to pass the Bearer token in your request

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Do you have any sample to explain me on how to create a token and to add it in the http call

Comment: I  will ad this to a class library solution and check and update.

Comment: what is request here?(request.ClientId, request.ClientSecret)

Comment: @jubi You should read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-create-service-principals

Comment: Do you know about RegistryManager.OpenAsync() method...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager.openasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_RegistryManager_OpenAsync

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196975/discussion-between-jubi-and-hariharan).

Comment: Instead of using a ClientId and ClientSecret you should use Managed Identity - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity

Comment: @HariHaran It is seeking for https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize .

Comment: @jubi yes. Once you have created svc principal you will have tenantId , ClientId , ClientSec use that for obtaining bearer token

Comment: @HariHaran unable to create oath2 token i am trying in postman. getting the error invalid_resource

Comment: @HariHaran Worked as expected. Now i have generated token and invoked the iot status API and it is working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HariHaran the above link was very much useful as i can check the availability of IoT hub also with the same API call.

Comment: @jubi don't chat in the comments

Comment: I will post another question and delete the existing chat